# Print Python Recursive Array

Tags: python, numpy

assume there are two A & R matrices which are 4x4 and 4x1:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import *

A = np.array([[0,1,1,1],
              [1,0,0,1],
              [0,0,0,1],
              [0,1,1,0]])
N = A.shape[1]  #number of nodes
R = np.ones((N,1))/N #initial rank of each node
```

and there is a function to transpose A matrix after normalizing, which is

```
def normalized_Adj_matrix_transpose(x):
    D = np.sum(x, axis = 1) # degree matrix
    normalized_Adj = x/D[:,np.newaxis] #normalize adj matirx
    return normalized_Adj.T
```

My goal is to keep updating R matrix until it converged, where R = ((A*D^-1)^T)^n.dot(R) for n is a real number.

```
R1 = normalized_Adj_matrix_transpose(A).dot(R)
R2 = normalized_Adj_matrix_transpose(A).dot(R1)
R3 = normalized_Adj_matrix_transpose(A).dot(R2)

print(R1.reshape((1,4)))
print(R2.reshape((1,4)))
print(R3.reshape((1,4)))
```

output:

```
[[0.125      0.20833333 0.20833333 0.45833333]]
[[0.10416667 0.27083333 0.27083333 0.35416667]]
[[0.13541667 0.21180556 0.21180556 0.44097222]]
```

My question is: how to use for loop to recursively update the R matrix and print each iteration result? many thanks

such as

```
iteration 1: [[0.125      0.20833333 0.20833333 0.45833333]]
iteration 2: [[0.10416667 0.27083333 0.27083333 0.35416667]]
iteration 3: [[0.13541667 0.21180556 0.21180556 0.44097222]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you put everything in a while loop with an if-condition in it that checks if `R1` is converging. Select a small enough `e` to check for convergence:

```
x = normalized_Adj_matrix_transpose(A)
R1 = R.copy()
e = np.array([10**(-9)]*(len(R))).reshape(-1,1)
R1_list = []
while True:
    R2 = x.dot(R1)
#    print(R1.reshape(1,4))
#    print(R2.reshape(1,4))
#    R1_list.append(R1.reshape(1,4))
    if ((R2 - R1) < e).all():
        break
    else:
        R1 = R2
```

Output:

```
print(R1.reshape(1,4))  #  [[0.12 0.24 0.24 0.4 ]]
print(R2.reshape(1,4))  #  [[0.12 0.24 0.24 0.4 ]]
```

You can uncomment `print` inside the loop to see how `R1` is converging but printing is not interesting in my opinion. If you want to maybe plot it later, it might be better to keep them in a list e.g. `R1_list` (you can also uncomment that and use it).

You can also optimize your `normalized_Adj_matrix_transpose` as:

```
def normalized_Adj_matrix_transpose(x):
    return A.T /A.sum(axis=1)
```